# Multiple user's AdMob IDs in one developer's account

Tags: android, admob

I'm an Android developer, I have an app published in my Google Play Dev Console, with AdMob banners added from my AdMob account.

Now I've created another app for my friend, and I want to publish it in my Google Play account, but to add code for his AdMob banners, using his AdMob account ID.

So, is it legal to use multiple user's AdMob IDs in one Google Play Dev account?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is requesting a legal opinion.